# How to get link of all users videos uploaded by him?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am working on facebook api and i want to get a link of users uploaded videos. i got an access_token with the permission to access photos. now how can i fetch the videos of the user using fql or graph api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just access [/me/videos](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/videos) via the graph api.

In FQL:

```
SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link,
       embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video 
WHERE owner=me()
```

Comment: I do not get all of the videos. And the results are inconsistent. Sometimes I get 2 results, then the next refresh I get 3, then the next I get 4, so on so forth - But never all of the videos. Is this a limitation in fql/facebook?